# How to use appSettings key in SqlDataSource

Tags: c#, asp.net, sqldatasource

Web.config:

```
<appSettings file="Application.config">
        <add key="stringC" value="Data Source=svr1;Initial Catalog=myDB;Integrated Security=FALSE;user=user2;pwd=@#$123pop;" />
</appSettings>
```

ASP.net:

```
<asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource1" runat="server"
    ConnectionString="<%$ {HOW TO USE THE APP SETTINGS KEY HERE} %>"
    SelectCommand="SELECT [au_id], [au_lname], [au_fname], [state] FROM [authors]" />
```

How do I replace the `{HOW TO USE THE APP SETTINGS KEY HERE}` with the application key.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use `<%$ ConfigurationSettings.AppSettings["stringC"] %>`.

```
<asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource1" runat="server"
    ConnectionString="<%$ ConfigurationSettings.AppSettings["stringC"] %>"
    SelectCommand="SELECT [au_id], [au_lname], [au_fname], [state] FROM [authors]" />
```

Answer (score 2):

In your `aspx` you want the following

```
ConnectionString="<%$ appSettings:stringC %>"
```